# Not being able to display the x-axis properly in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

The data provided is just a small subset of the data I am working with. It is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

time <- c(0, 0.0166666666666667, 0.0333333333333333, 0.05, 0.0666666666666667, 
          0.0833333333333333)
sent_score <- c(-8L, -1L, -49L, -26L, -8L, -18L)

data = data.frame(time,sent_score)

ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = sent_score)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    ggtitle("Sentiment Scores By Time") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(seq(0, 23, 1)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "red", linetype = 2) + 
    xlab("Time")
```

[image]

The data is displayed properly, but I am not able to display the x-axis correctly. Please do let me know if I am doing something wrong. Thank You in advance!

Comment: Can you include an image of the plot and let us know what, specifically, you think is wrong with the x-axis? The x-axis and the plot in general look fine to me when I run your code.

Comment: You can check out the image at https://github.com/adhok/errors/blob/master/test.png

Comment: Ok, so what's wrong with it?

Comment: The x-axis should be labelled as "Time" instead of 0

Comment: Ah, you mean the title of the x-axis. The problem is in `scale_x_continuous`. You need to name the `breaks` argument, otherwise it gets interpreted as the `name` argument, since `name` is by default the first argument of `scale_x_continuous`. Zero is the first value in the sequence, so the x-axis title became `0`. The code should instead be: `scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,23,1))`, which can be shortened to `scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:23)`. (It would have been easier to spot this if you'd formatted your code into a human-readable form (e.g., by putting each ggplot statement on a new line.))